# To which file path should I set my JAVA_HOME path?

Tags: java, shell, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

I have two files in my `'usr/lib/jvm/'` path namely `"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"` and `"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"`.  The icon on the `"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"` file is a folder with a black downward curving arrow.  When I look at the properties of the `"/usrlib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"` file it says its 'Link target' is `"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"`.  What does that mean?

The reason I am asking is because I want to try to solve the `KeyError: 'JAVA_HOME'` I receive when importing `jnius`, which means I have to try the solution given at https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/issues/209. The solution is to set the right path for 'JAVA_HOME'.

#### Tried

I noticed when I checked the `-version` of java in the terminal it only gave `"/usrlib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"`.  Does that mean that the 'JAVA_HOME' is this path or the other.

Which of the two file paths above is 'JAVA_HOME'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found a symbolic link, which is usually shortened to "symlink".

If you're familiar with Windows, it's equivalent to a "shortcut". It's a tiny file that simply points to another file or directory.

You can run `man ln` in a terminal to read more about links (both symlinks and hard links).

Regarding your final question: they should be functionally equivalent at this point. I would recommend the shorter one (the symlink). That way, you won't have to update your environment variable if you install another jdk8 version (e.g. upgrade to 1.8.1, or choose another implementation with `update-java-alternatives`) in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Your answer was very consice and informative and I can finally import jnius.

Comment: No worries. Have fun! :)